# Multi-variate turtle movement

Tags: netlogo

I need some help with some coding that has me stumped!

I have flies (a turtle breed) on a field. The field has green patches (grass) and brown and grey patches (two types of dung). There is a "patches own" which is the age of the dung (green patches = 0 and brown and grey patches increase +1 per tick).

This is what I need to happen: the flies need to move to the freshest dung within a certain radius and remain there until the dung disappears. If there is no dung within the radius they must move about randomly.

The way I have been looking about it is to use some combination of an IF statement, radius function and the downhill function (however I am not sure if that lets me select a radius or not).

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

**I have recently made some advances. I can get the flies to move randomly within a radius, but I can't specify which patches within that area the flies are allowed to go to.*

*[move-to one-of patches in-radius 892]*

*I can also make it so the flies go to the patch with the lowest patches own, but cannot specify that this patch must be of a certain colour and within a certain radius.*

*[move-to min-one-of patches [dung-score]]**

Answer (score 3):

It might help if you combine `in-radius`, `min-one-of` and `with`. eg:

```
move-to min-one-of patches in-radius 10 with [member? pcolor [brown green]] [dung-score]
```

if there's a chance that the `with` block might return an empty agentset, you might want to test for condition to avoid an error. eg:

```
let candidates patches in-radius 10 with [member? pcolor [brown green]]
if any? candidates [move-to min-one-of candidates [dung-score] ]
```